# Open .csv file in MS Excel gives wrong Utf-8 formatting (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, csv, utf-8, export-to-excel, byte-order-mark

I have been searching forever for an answer for this and now I think I have ended up in an infinite loop of googling.

I am using javascript to export data to a .csv file. No issues here, it opens flawless in Apple's Numbers & Google spreadsheet. Unfortunately for me my customer is using MS Excel on both Mac & Windows and is, to say the least, not very tech savvy. So using the "import" option in Excel is to really push their boundaries. Although it gives the correct formatting after selecting the right options.

So, **the problem is**: .csv file is not opening with correct formatting in Excel when double clicking or choosing "open with..". **"Ö" is being displayed as "Ã¶"** for example. I have come across a lot of answers suggesting adding a **BOM** to the file, however I haven't found the correct way of doing this. Is this a string value I put in the first cell, or is this something that needs to be in the javascript code while writing the file?

I am using "," as separator in the .csv file.

Any help that is deriving to the solution of this issue will result in eternal gratitude and appreciation.

The application is a iOS and Android written in javascript in Appcelerator Titanium. The code for writing the .csv file is as follows, where "input" is an array:

```
exports.exportCsvData = function(input)
{

var rowTxt = "";
for(var i=0;i < input.length; i++){ // row iteration
    for(var j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++){ // column iteration
        rowTxt += '"' + input[i][j] + '"';

        if(j < (input[i].length-1))
        {
            rowTxt += ',';
        }
    }
    rowTxt += '\n';// adding new line at end of row
}

// creating output file in application data directory
var outputFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'min_traningsdagbok.txt');
// writing data in output file 
    outputFile.write(rowTxt); 


if(outputFile.exists){
    Ti.API.info("CSV generated!!!");
}

// return output file path
return outputFile.nativePath;    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone ending up here for the same reason:

Needless to say there is a huge issue regarding Utf-8 formatting in CSV files on different spreedsheet clients. Especially MS Excell. My solution was to give up the CSV file and output a .html file, containing a html table. This opens correctly on both Windows and Mac MS Excel.

```
var htmlHead = '<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> </head> <body><table style="width:300px"><table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">';

    var str = "";

        str += htmlHead;

            for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
               str += '<tr>';
               for (var j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++){
                  str += '<td>' +  input[i][j] + '</td>';
               }
               str += '</tr>';
            }

            str += '</table>';

    var htmlEnd = '</body> </html>';

outputFileHtml.write(htmlHead+str+htmlEnd);
```